# On Facebook's own website LIKE buttons are instantanious, but on my website they can take up to 30 seconds to render

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, embed, fbml, xfbml

This question has been bugging me for a long time, and since I found no discussion of it anywhere, I figured I'd finally start one.

If you go to Facebook's own website (Example: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)), and scroll to the bottom of the page, you will see an implementation of the "Like + Share" buttons.

These are the same buttons which you can implement on your own website as well ([Facebook Like Button Configurator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator)), with one major difference:

On Facebook's own website the buttons load instantaneously, and by that I mean there is not even a 1 second delay. They render as if they were regular text. It's that fast.

However, it is a completely different story when it comes to rendering these buttons when embedding them on your website. These facebook 'like' elements are always the last to load and are the slowest. For first time visitors it can take up to 20-30 seconds for the facebook elements to render.

The code is implemented to the letter as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MyFacebookPage/" 
data-layout="button_count" 
data-action="like" 
data-size="large" 
data-show-faces="true" 
data-share="false">
</div>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '123456789',
        xfbml      : true,
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.async=true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding dns-prefetch headers in the `<head>` tag for facebook's domains hoping to speed things up, but it doesn't seem to have had much effect.

```
<head>
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.facebook.com" />
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//staticxx.facebook.com" />
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//connect.facebook.net" />
</head>
```

I tried digging a little deeper, and one difference I noticed from looking at the code used on facebook.com's implementation was that they used the fbml version of the code `<fb:like></fb:like>`, as opposed to the code that they provide us, the end users, to implement the buttons on our own websites.

I've also noticed that there was no link to "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js", which is the script we are meant to use. This seems to suggest facebook are perhaps using a custom stripped down version of the script specific to their implementation of the 'like buttons' only?

This is just my limited analysis, as I'm an amateur web developer and am no expert in xbml. Hope someone can shed some light on this.

One thing that is for certain: Facebook's own implementation of the "LIKE" buttons is totally different from the one they are instructing us to do, and the speed difference is astronomical.

Can anyone shed some light on this?
Ideally, can anyone suggest how to make our implementation of the "like button" code more like that of Facebook's own implementation, so that we can also enjoy the speed benefits?

Comment: You can either embed the iframe version directly instead of letting them render via the SDK, or load the SDK synchronously instead of async as it is doing now. (But be aware, that if Facebook should respond slower than usual, your site will “hang” as well.) Apart from that, there is little you can do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I did try iframe method, but the problem I had with it was that `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() {})` didn't work with it. As for the synchronous load, that is indeed not an option for exactly the reasons that you mentioned. I would however really like to get to the bottom of how Facebook implements it on their own site to load so fast, and possibly adapt their "technique" for our use.

Comment: Just to update, I experimented with using the `<fb:like></fb:like>` xfbml tags, instead of the HTML5 code `<div class="fb-like">...</div>` and the load times seem to be noticeably much faster. I read on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645221/like-button-xfbml-or-iframe) that it's a lot faster to parse xfbml tags in the DOM than going through all the classes. This is how facebook themselves implement the code on their site. However, this method does not seem to be officially supported anymore (even though it works). Is there any downside to using it in the long run?

Comment: Where does it say there that XFBML was a lot faster? I can’t really believe it makes much of a difference - and if it does, then probably rather due to SDK internals, than how the relevant elements are selected. If selection via tag name vs class makes a difference, then that should still be within the realm of microseconds.

Comment: Hey CBroe, thanks for your comment! I didn't say that it said so anywhere, I was only speaking from personal experience. After having started using the fb:like tags I saw a noticeable difference in performance. Where you can notice the difference the most is with Mobile devices, particularly older ones (I have a Galaxy S5). On Desktop or on more powerful devices it's harder to notice. But the performance increase is definitely there. For whatever reason, be it SDK internals (likely cause), the Like button is parsed and rendered much faster (I would say at least 2x faster is not more).

Comment: Hm, okay, in regard to older browsers I can imagine it making a difference - when stuff like querySelectorAll etc. to query the DOM is not available, it might be faster if it just need a getElementsByTagName call, instead of having to loop through elements and check what class they have while doing so. But in that regard, using FB.XFBML.parse to only look inside a specific DOM element (so SDK init with xfbml:false) should be able to speed things up considerably, especially on a page with only one like button (or maybe a handful.)

Comment: The device itself is older in my case (Galaxy S5), but the browser is the latest version of Chrome. As for FB.XFBML.parse(), yes I actually tried that and it worked. Performance was also better as well. However for some reason it had an unintended side effect of screwing up the sliding animation for my `<div>` element which contained the 'Like' button. for some reason it added a weird flicker/jitter to the animation which I was unable to resolve, and so I opted not to use that for this reason. But yes, using FB.XFBML.parse(), while setting xfbml to 'false' inside FB.Init() works too!